# Ng-table filter exact match angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have the following function:

```
    function updateTable(lines) {
     // console.log("dit is de filter", $scope.filter);
        lines = lines || [];
        $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
            filter: $scope.filter,
            sorting: { name: "asc" }
        }, {
            dataset: lines,
            counts: lines.length > 10 ? [ 10, 20, 50, 100 ] : []
        });
    }
```

Is there a way to add exact filtering to this function. I tried adding the true parameter on filter but that didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the log entails

dit is de filter 
{}
municipalityName: ""
productProfile: ""
segment: ""
year: ""

Comment: If you want to eleborate on your question, edit the question, do not add it as an answer